# preserve ftp or sftp timestamp php upload

Tags: php, ftp, windows-xp, sftp

I need to use php to upload files to a ftp or sftp server that is installed on a Windows XP PC.

How I can upload a file from php preserving the timestamp?

Comment: This is two questions in one that have nothing to do with each other really, I would recommend to ask them separately. Also, you should expand a little on what you are planning to do: Will the Windows XP machine be always online? Will it have a static IP?

Comment: I don't care if the Windoxs XP machine is always online and has a stati IP. I already know how to solve that...
I only want to know which is the best free ftp server that with a php function can preserve the timestamp on upload.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a PHP web application, used from a browser on a Windows XP machine?

You cannot conserve the timestamp because PHP can only see what the browser sends, But the browser doesn't send this information. :-(

Otherwise for a windows SFTP client I suggest Putty PSFTP, and PLINK if you need to automate it.

Comment: I need to use it throught php. What I have to do?

Comment: If you mean a PHP web application, there is nothing you can do from HTML at all because the browser doesn't send the modification date of the file.

However Flash can do this and there are pay-for flash file upload controls which can give you access to this information.

For example a web search found this. I haven't tried it but it says it can do what you want.
http://www.easyalgo.com/eaflashupload.aspx